# Asynchronous Programming Model when no data is available from a socket

Tags: c#, sockets

I want to read from a socket in an asynchronous way.

If I used the synchronous code below

```
StreamReader aReadStream = new StreamReader(aStream);
String aLine = aReadStream.ReadLine(); // application might hand here
```

with a valid open connection, but no data available for reading, the application would hang at the ReadLine() function.

If I switch to the code below using Asynchronous Programming Model

```
NetworkStream aStream = aClient.GetStream();
while(true)
{
     IAsyncResult res = aStream.BeginRead(data, 0, data.Length, null, null);
     if (res.IsCompleted){
          Trace.WriteLine("here");                            
     } else {
          Thread.Sleep(100);
     }
}
```

In the same scenario what would happen? If there is no data to read, the variable `res` would appear as `Completed` or not?

Most important, when there is no data to read, all of my calls in that while loop to `aStream.BeginRead()` are they scheduled continuously in the Thread Pool? If this is true am I risking to  degrade the application performances because the Thread Pool has increased too much its size?

Thanks for the help

AFG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By writing the code in this way, you've basically made it synchronous.

The proper way to make this code work is to call BeginRead, passing a callback handler which will process the data which has been read when it is ready, then go do other work rather than just entering a loop.

The callback handler you specify will also be triggered when the data stream is terminated (e.g. because the connection was closed) which you can handle appropriately.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.beginread.aspx for a sample.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this article which I wrote that covers asynchronous sockets here on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/redirsrvr.aspx) which is what I learnt from the "[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300760.aspx), August 2005, 'Winsock - Get closer to the wire with high-performance sockets in .NET', Daryn Kiely, Pg 81."

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.